# Assume $S \subset \Omega, $ $\lambda^*(S) = 0$. Show that there exists a set $A \in \mathscr A$ such that $S \subset A$ and $\lambda(S) = 0$

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $(\Omega, \mathscr A, \lambda)$ be a measure space.
>
> Now, assume $S \subset \Omega, $ $\lambda^*(S) = 0$. Show that there exists a set $A \in \mathscr A$ such that $S \subset A$ and $\lambda(S) = 0$.

My attempt:

Following the definition of the outer measure, we get that

$\lambda^*(S) = \inf \{\lambda(A) : A \supset S, A \in \mathscr A^{\uparrow}\} = 0$.

So, since we know that this equals $0$, and since we are talking about the infinum, there must be such an $A \supset S$ with $\lambda(A) = 0$. What's left is that we only know that $A \in \mathscr A^{\uparrow}$ so far, but we want that $A \in \mathscr A$. But since $\mathscr A$ is part of the measure space defined before, $\mathscr A$ has to be a $\sigma$-algebra, which means that $\mathscr A = \mathscr A^{\uparrow}$.

Is that correct?

Comment: What is $\mathscr A^{\uparrow}$?

Comment: Set of all sets that can be written as a countable union of $A_k \in \mathscr A$. Isn't that the general notation for it?

Comment: I haven't seen that notation before.

Comment: What would be the general notation then? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, since we know that this equals $0$, and since we are talking about the infinum, there must be such an $A \supset S$ with $\lambda(A) = 0$

That's not true in general!
You only know that for each $\varepsilon$ there exists $A_\varepsilon$ such that $A_{\varepsilon} \supset S$ and $\lambda(A_\varepsilon) \le \varepsilon$.

THAT'S the definition about the infimum, nothing else!
(To make that clear, consider the set $X = \{\frac{1}{n}, n\in\Bbb N\}$, then $\inf X = 0$ but there is no $n\in\Bbb N$ s.t $\frac{1}{n} = 0$)

So if we consider $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{n}$ we get: $A_n \supset S, \lambda(A_n) \le \frac{1}{n}$

Then Define $$A = \bigcap_{n\in\Bbb n} A_n$$ and you are done.